# ElementCollection with same collectiontable

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations

I want to store `emailIds` that needs to be notified when a change happens into a table.
**I only have one table with columns ownerid and emailid**. I want to store `emailid` in separate rows, rather than a comma separated list. I don't need a **owner table**, because i dont have any other information for the owner. I just want to save the emailids, but into separate rows.

how do i do that in hibernate.

I tried using something like this

```
@Table(name = "OwnerEmailIds")
@Entity
public class OwnerEmailIds implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5906661729869048121L;

@Column(name = "OwnerID", nullable = false)
private String ownerId;


@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) // must use eager as we close the session before returning
   @CollectionTable(name="OwnerEmailIds", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="vendorId"))
   @Column(name = "emailId")
private Set<String> EmailIds = new HashSet<String>();
```

But problem here is my collection table is same as the entity table.

And as my emailIds column in not null, when i try to save the object it fails with sql error stating emailid column can't be null.

Comment: How do you intend to use the data in this table? How would you query it with hibernate?

Comment: I get the ownerID from the different web service, and i just need to get the emailids from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is to put collection in multiple rows and repeat other values, in you case email list will be inserted and owner_id will repeated for it's emails.

Hibernate does not provide any configuration for that. You have to do it manually.

You can do what you are looking for using the following structure and code. You must have a primary key, here you can make your email id as primary key or you can add an autoincrement integer id.

```
@Table(name = "OwnerEmailIds")
@Entity
public class OwnerEmailIds implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5906661729869048121L;

    @Column(name = "OwnerID", nullable = false)
    private String ownerId;

    @Id   
    @Column(name = "emailId")
    private String emailId;

    //setter and getters
}
```

Then you iterate through the list of email ids and create the below object and then save them individually. You can not create a collection object and configure hibernate to store them in the current table in multiple rows.

```
//loop throught the list of email ids
OwnerEmailIds oei = new OwnerEmailIds();
oei.setOwnerId("first last name");
oei.setEmailId("some@somedomain.com");
session.save(oei);
```

If you make emailId as primary key then you will have to make sure that no two owners has same email id. If that is the case then you have to add another auto_increment primary key.

Comment: What if i dont need a Owners table in the database. I just need to store the owner email ids?

Comment: Then you just need OwnerEmailId table and create collection your self and save them all.

Comment: Yes, my model requires more than one emailid for each owner. And i want to store them in separate rows

Comment: I think what you are asking is that you want an implementation where you, store an object and it should create as many rows as many are there in the list provided.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in hibernate, Simple rule is that one object always represents one row.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to map an entity to a table, Hibernate requires a unique id property, that maps to a unique (primary) key on the table.

As you have stated that you don't have this and if this is the only table your application is using, then Hibernate might not be the best choice.

You could still get the required information through Hibernate from your database by executing a native SQL query:

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select OwnerID from OwnerEmailIds where emailId = :email");
q.setScalar("OwnerID", StandardBasicTypes.LONG);
q.setParameter("email", emailId)
List<Long> ids = (List<Long>) q.list();
```

Storing the ids could also be done with a native query, but here you would have to take into account data that is already there, so it is a little harder.